# How to shorten the LINQ query to calculate the sum for parent table from child tables

Tags: c#, linq

Currently I have this LINQ query which calculate the totalcount of a parent table (`CafeTables`) from child tables (`CafeTableDetails`). These code works. But somehow, I believe these code can the shorten.

```
var selectedTable = db.CafeTables.Where(c => c.TableNo.Equals(userName)).SingleOrDefault();

var selectedTableDetailsRaw = db.CafeTableDetails.
    Where(cd => cd.CafeTableId == selectedTable.Id);

selectedTable.TotalOrders = selectedTableDetailsRaw.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use linq `JOIN` and `GroupBy` to make it.

```
var result = db.CafeTables.Where(c => c.TableNo == userName)
                         .Join(db.CafeTableDetails.GroupBy(x=>x.CafeTableId)
                         .Select(g => new { CafeTableId = g.Key, cnt = g.Count() }), 
st => st.Id,
cd => cd.CafeTableId,
(st,cd) => new  
{
    st.Id,
    cd.cnt
    //..... your expect property
});
```